# Why do I see black screen in game after download my game from google play?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

my game was Played on All Devices so 
I released my game on google play SO It plays on some devices android (So it's Ok) but does not play on some devices and see balck screen ( only)( for Example: sumsung mobile ) after Download it,Why?
This is my game link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Dezi.prisondogssummer
check it on your devices and tell me "Do you see black screen or played game" , and if it is black screen , why?
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

There probably is an error with the application that the user can't see. I advise you to run this in an emulator or link your device to your pc and emulate it locally. When you have the emulator (or device linked up) ready, you can debug and see exactly what the error is. 
If you have trouble on certain devices, check your SDK level and test on multiple emulated devices. 
Chances are the problem is a deprecated item or a version level error.

Comment: Stef Havermans,so what is "emulator"? is it  "BlueStacks" if yes , so how do I  see debug on them , IN CASE SDK : I used from min android 4.1  and download 5gb sdk API 7 TO API 14 BUT I seen it do not work on Android 8.00, why?  thanks again